# PuppeteerSharp ClickAsync get content

Tags: c#, puppeteer

I was trying to press a button and then download PDF on puppeter.

```
     await page.WaitForSelectorAsync("#bGeneratePDF");
     var click = page.ClickAsync("bGeneratePDF");
```

The page has a IMG that if I convert to PDF right away I download just a blank PDF. If I click this button a "save as box" appers on the screen, but how do I get the content/save it?

Comment: Hey @danielr, is not quite clear what you are asking...

Comment: @hardkoded oh hello :), nice repo btw, I'm asking if someone know a way to get the content of the "save as box" that appears after I click the download button with puppteer and download it, this var click is just a attempt of mine to debug.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of that "save as box" that doesn't sound familiar to me.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/uav01t

Comment: I'm afraid that dialog is not supported by the devtools protocol.

Comment: it's okay, scanning the url I discovered a query 'print=1' that returns a gif that I can convert to PDF, thank you for the attention anyway, used your port to solve 5 urls downloads of the 8 that I need.